# Hammer JS - pan up

Tags: javascript, jquery, hammer.js

I am looking to invoke code when a user scrolls up using a tablet device (Modernizr Present):

```
if ( $('html').hasClass('touch') ){
    $(window).hammer().on('panup', function(){
        console.log("pan'd up");
    });
}
```

On load I get this error:

[image]

What is the best way to implement the API's, I have already got the libraries. Including the jquery plugin from hammerjs team:

- hammer.min.js
- jquery.hammer.js

Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing this wrapped in a ready callback? If you arent, the element might not yet be defined.

Something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // your code here
});
```